# How can I write Java code in Eclipse to access data stored in a Domino database?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, eclipse-plugin, lotus-domino

I wanted to import the domino database project (nsf) to the eclipse by programmatically.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What does mean "programmatically"? You mean source of project?

Comment: yes i need to get the source of the notes database in java perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, you would need to export the NSF to DXL. This will give you an XML representation of the whole database. After that you can access it in eclipse.

The following sample LotusScript code will export a database (example only)

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim nsn As New NotesSession
    Dim ndb As NotesDatabase
    Dim ndc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim ndo As NotesDocument
    Dim ndxle As NotesDXLExporter
    Dim nst As NotesStream

    On Error Resume Next

    Set ndb = nsn.CurrentDatabase
    Set ndc = ndb.UnprocessedDocuments
    Set ndo = ndc.GetFirstDocument

    Set nst = nsn.createStream

    If (Not(nst.Open( "c:\DATA.xml" ))) Then
        Print "Open File DATA.xml Failed" 
    End If

    nst.truncate

    Set ndxle = nsn.CreateDXLExporter (ndo, nst)
    Call ndxle.Process()
    Msgbox ndxle.Log
    Call nst.Close()
End Sub
```

Although I'd recommend reading up on DXL in the infocenter, as there are a large number of options to consider when doing this.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXPORTING_AND_IMPORTING_DXL_JAVA.html

Be aware that Domino Designer is actually built on Eclipse. So you can right click any design element and "View Source" to see the DXL format.

Also if you use the Team functionality it will convert the NSF to DXL so that it can be easily integrated to source control systems.

Some more details here:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/3.7_Source_control